# J2ME plataformRequest with USSD sometimes work's

Tags: java-me, ussd

I do an aplication that reports valance
I simply call

```
platformRequest("tel:*222#");
```

Where *222# is the way to get valance in my network
Work in Samnsug for the moment 
But in Some Lg istead of do ussd do a voice call and of course fail

I want to know if are a way to force do a ussd intead a voice call to *222#
for this phones.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that J2ME does not support the USSD protocol because in the JSR 120 for messaging the specifications does not tell us that the USSD protocol needs to be implemented by the provider API company. See this link to get more info: 
http://javatnews.blogspot.com/2012/06/ussd-in-j2me-or-jme.html
Greetings, Pavel

Comment: This depends of the phone Midlet implementation , for someones works and others nothing I put my app here http://developers.cubava.cu/2015/08/31/appaplicacion-java-para-transferencia-de-saldo-99-etc/  regards
Is Pavel Serrat??